# How do I pass in value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui

My question is how do I pass in the `value` in `function(value)`?I don't know how to search the official documents for this problem.

```js
<script>
    var value = "shang zheng yu";
    var vm = kendo.observable({
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        fullName: function(value) {
            if (value !== undefined) {
                var name = value.split(" ");

                this.set("firstName", name[0]);
                this.set("lastName", name[1]);
            } else {
                return this.get("firstName") + " " + this.get("lastName");
            }
        }
    });

    kendo.bind(document.body, vm);
</script>
```

```html
Copy code<p>Full Name: <input data-bind="value: fullName"></p>
<p>First Name: <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span></p>
<p>Last Name: <span data-bind="text: lastName"></span></p>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that observable wrapper is working, but `vm.fullName("your string here")` should do the trick in normal js coding

Comment: @ Samridh Tuladhar,thanks，It really works

Answer (score 0):

well the object has a key which in itself is an object, a function in this case, it should simply work like any other function stored in an object
eg:

```
const myFuncInVariable = (a) => {
  console.log(a)
}
```

you call this function by calling `myFuncInVariable("something")` which logs `something`

similarly here, the `vm.fullName` here contains a function, which can be called like any other function  in  a variable by

```
vm.fullName(value);
```